# How to connect angular2 server side with php

Tags: node.js, angular

I recently bought a new template for my site written in angular2, i did a short course on it and started to work and everything fine.

Now come the the part where i try to connect it to my DataBase and i cant figure it out...

after a little bit of reading i saw that i need to use nodejs in order to speak with the server side, is that true?

can i use php or i must use the nodejs api to work with my Db?

am i missing the concept of the angular2 or something? can someone post a basic script of angular working with php example , i just  cant find it.. :(

thanks  a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The most common scenario is that you use the [`Http`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html) service in Angular that makes XHR (Ajax) requests to the server to fetch data (not HTML).

You can use any server that is able to receive, process and response to XHR requests. Therefore PHP is as suiteable as node.js (or .NET, Java, or any other web server)

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html